# How to dynamically add/remove HTML attributes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to either add/remove the onclick attribute from my repeater based on conditions.  How can i access each individual one in the databound event to remove or add that attribute?

```
<asp:repeater id="repLinks" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>
        <div id="vehicle-link-<%# Eval("ID")%>" class="vehicle-link">
            <a class="btn <%=IIf(Listing.IsResponsive, "btn-default", "accent-color1 palette-bg2 palette-border2")%>" href="<%# Eval("Href")%>" target="<%# Eval("Target") %>" onclick="<%# Eval("OnClick")%>"><%# Eval("Label")%></a>
        </div>
     </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>


Private Sub repLinks_OnItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repLinks.ItemDataBound
    dim row  As HtmlTableRow= CType(e.Item.FindControl("repLinks"), HtmlTableRow) 
    if (not row is  Nothing)
        row.Attributes("onmouseover") = string.Format("alert('Hello from row #{0}');", e.Item.ItemIndex )
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What element are you trying to add the onclick functionality?

Comment: @AdamCarr Right now I'm trying to remove it from each Anchor tag in the itemtemplate

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the anchor tag a server side control.

Your better off using

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Id="cLinkButton"><%# Eval("Label")%>
</asp:LinkButton>

Private Sub repLinks_OnItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repLinks.ItemDataBound
   Dim button = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("cPersonButton"), LinkButton)


    if (not button is Nothing)

       c.Click +=  // add logic to bind click event here.
    End If
End Sub
```

You will have to decorate the control with the other logic in this event as well.  You can get the actual object that has been databound from e.Item.DataItem, you just need to cast that to the correct class.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, clicking the hyperlink may prevent the event from firing.